# Regex - variable name in string

Tags: regex

I'm looking for the proper regex to find a variable's name in a string. My sample variable is:

BLAB_LA_BLA

(could be any correct var. name). 
I want to take everything that is not a "w" so "W" and my variables name in a string could be at the beginning as well as at the end of the string so i added anchors "^" and "$" to my regex.

This is my regex:

```
 (\W|^)BLAB_LA_BLA(\W|$)
```

This is my text:

ifc(COUNT[*]>0,BLAB_LA_BLA,'')

My match is:

,BLAB_LA_BLA,

I have no idea how to get a correct regex which takes only the name without commas.

Of course I don't want to match with my variable, names such as:

"BLAB", "*LAB*", "_BLA" etc.

Comment: Was it really necessary to add 3 different language tags to that question?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: I think `\b` is what you are looking for. Use `\b` instead of `\W`

Comment: Strangely, you describe a word boundary, but never occurs to you to use one ...

Comment: Yes I was looking for \b. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this Regular Expression-

```
/^(\w)*BLAB_LA_BLA(\w)*$/
```

`\w`: finds **word** character

`\W`: finds **non-word** character

Comment: Which programming/scripting language are you using? Could you please post some of your code here.